# Escaping Numeric IDs for QuerySelector - Unexpected Double Backslashes

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working with SVG elements in a TypeScript project and need to query `foreignObject` elements by their parent `g` element's IDs. Some of these IDs start with a digit, so I'm using a function to escape the ID appropriately for use in `document.querySelector`.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the escaped ID seems to be represented with double backslashes in the debugger, leading to query selection failures.

In the SVG structure:

```html
<g id="3735df69-8da5-45a9-8580-ffd0e50b3111" transform="translate(200,200)">...</g>
<g id="080640d2-e040-4c6b-b943-7311327f8129" transform="translate(300,200)">...</g>
```

And here is the function I'm using to sanitize the IDs:

```
function sanitizeId(id: string) {
  if (/^\d/.test(id)) {
    return id.replace(/^(\d)/, "\\3$1 ").replace(/([^\w-])/g, "\\$1");
  } else {
    return id;
  }
}

const selector = `#${sanitizeId(props.__rd3t.id)} foreignObject`;
const foreignObject = document.querySelector(String(selector));
```

When I console.log the selector, I see the following output:

```
#\\33\ 735df69-8da5-45a9-8580-ffd0e50b3111 foreignObject
```

However, in the debugger, the selector evaluates to:

```
#\\\\33\\ 735df69-8da5-45a9-8580-ffd0e50b3111 foreignObject
```

I'm confused about why the escaped ID is showing up with double backslashes in the debugger and how this affects document.querySelector. How can I correctly escape these numeric IDs for use in CSS selectors in TypeScript? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.replace(/([^\w-])/g, "\\$1");` prefixes the slash you added in the previous replace with another slash. Not sure why you're trying to escape a UUID though? `[^\w-]` replaces all non-word characters except `-`

Comment: @phuzi _"Not sure why you're trying to escape a UUID though?"_ - because the `#id` selector in CSS (or applied in JS, via querySelector) does not work, if the ID value starts with a number.

Comment: You don't need to escape the value, if you use the attribute selector instead of the ID selector: `document.querySelector('[id="3735df69-8da5-45a9-8580-ffd0e50b3111"]')` (The ID selector has a higher specificity, than the attribute selector - but that should hardly matter for this kind of use case.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you, that works great. Much appreciated

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin _"Does he understand that HTML5 allows id's to start with a number?"_ - yes, but do you understand, that the ID selector in CSS _doesn't_ though? And they were trying to use one of those with `querySelector`. In a stylesheet, `#123` as selector would simply not do much, but when used in JS, it will throw an actual error. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes has details on what CSS identifiers can, and can't contain, and which special cases will need escaping. Or, as here, a workaround by using a different method of selection to begin with.

Comment: I do understand the first char needs to be the unicode escape. Never stumbled on it because I never did this to myself in 17 years. If he is willing to replace and escape these ids, then why wouldn't he do `str.replace(/(?<=id=")[0-9]/g, function(m,o,s){
    return `_${m}`
})` and spare himself the mess of this special treatment for digits?